# Count entre 2 columnas de 2 tablas

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo estas 2 tablas

tabla 1

```
----------------------------------
|   articulo   |   Ubicacion     |
----------------------------------
|     200116    |   cy1112       | 
----------------------------------
|     200116    |   ee3091       |
----------------------------------
```

tabla 2

```
----------------------------------
|   articulo   |   Ubicacion     |
----------------------------------
|     200116    |   cy1112       | 
----------------------------------
|     200116    |   dd3091       |
----------------------------------
```

Lo estoy tratando de hacer de esta manera

`SI_Ubicacion = COUNT(DISTINCT ISNULL(tabla1.SI_Ubicacion,tabla2.SI_Ubicacion))`

es que me cuente las ubicaciones y si son la misma no contarla 2 veces y el resultado debe de ser  `SI_Ubicacion = 3`

En este momento solo me esta contando las ubicaciones de la primera tabla

Las tablas están relacionadas por el `articulo`

Espero que me puedan ayuda,
Gracias.

Comment: No se entiende bien la pregunta. Y si es posible explica cuál es la relación entre tabla1 y tabla2.

Comment: Ya mejore el contenido.

Comment: Sigue sin ser claro. Para una mejor respuesta es bueno que indiques por ejemplo si hay ubicaciones que podrían estar en la tabla1 y no en la tabla2 y viceversa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta con hacer un `UNION` entre ambas tablas:

```
SELECT
     Articulo
    ,Ubicacion
FROM @t1
UNION
SELECT
     Articulo
    ,Ubicacion
FROM @t2
```

El cual te entrega el siguiente resultado:

```
+----------+-----------+
| Articulo | Ubicacion |
+----------+-----------+
| 200116   | cy1112    |
+----------+-----------+
| 200116   | dd3091    |
+----------+-----------+
| 200116   | ee3091    |
+----------+-----------+
```

Para sacar el total de registros quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT SI_Ubicacion = COUNT(Ubicacion)
FROM (
    SELECT
         Articulo
        ,Ubicacion
    FROM @t1
    UNION
    SELECT
         Articulo
        ,Ubicacion
    FROM @t2
) AS T1
```

El cual te entrega los siguientes resultados:

```
+--------------+
| SI_Ubicacion |
+--------------+
| 3            |
+--------------+
```

Aquí puedes ver la <kbd>[demostración y sus resultados](http://rextester.com/CDUGV65408)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

No se logra entender bien la pregunta, pero asumo que si hay las tablas que indicas estan relacionadas por un articulo debe existir una **tabla articulo**, entonces puedes hacer una union de la **tabla1** y la **tabla2** y luego esa union relacionarla con tu tabla **articulo** para finalmente hacer un group by.

Aqui te dejo un ejemplo de lo que te menciono:
[ver ejemplo](http://rextester.com/TBY32288)

```
select a.nombre, count(ubicaciones.ubicacion)
from articulo a , (
    select * from tabla1 union select * from tabla2
    ) as ubicaciones
where a.codigo = ubicaciones.articulo
group by a.nombre;
```

Nota: **recuerda que la UNION de dos querys omite los valores iguales**

Si no esta claro trata de mejorar tu pregunta, que se entiende muy poco.

Answer (score 1):

Tal como dice Andrés, la respuesta pasa por el uso del `UNION` para sumar las dos tablas de ubicaciones y aprovechar que ésta sentencia ya nos quita los registros duplicados, pero **prestar atención** el `UNION` toma en cuenta la fila completa para determinar duplicados por lo que el `SELECT` debiera recuperar solo `articulo` y `ubicacion`, si agregásemos otro campo que no se repite estaríamos contando mal las ubicaciones.

La idea sería la siguiente:

```
DECLARE @Articulo TABLE(articulo int, nombre VARCHAR(255))
DECLARE @t1 TABLE(articulo int, ubicacion varchar(30))
DECLARE @t2 TABLE(articulo int, ubicacion varchar(30)
)

INSERT INTO @Articulo VALUES(200116, 'Articulo 200116')
INSERT INTO @Articulo VALUES(200117, 'Articulo 200117')
INSERT INTO @Articulo VALUES(200118, 'Articulo 200118')

INSERT INTO @t1 VALUES(200116, 'cy1112')
INSERT INTO @t1 VALUES(200116, 'ee3091')
INSERT INTO @t1 VALUES(200116, 'xx3092')
INSERT INTO @t2 VALUES(200116, 'cy1112')
INSERT INTO @t2 VALUES(200116, 'dd3091')
INSERT INTO @t2 VALUES(200118, 'dd3091')

SELECT  A.articulo, 
    A.nombre,  
    ISNULL(COUNT(T.ubicacion),0) AS 'Ubicaciones'
        FROM @Articulo A
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT articulo, ubicacion FROM @t1 UNION
                SELECT articulo, ubicacion FROM @t2) T
        ON A.articulo = T.articulo
    GROUP BY A.articulo,
        A.nombre
```

La salida:

```
articulo    nombre          ubicaciones
=========== =============== ===========
200.116,00  Articulo 200116 4,00
200.117,00  Articulo 200117 0,00
200.118,00  Articulo 200118 1,00
```

Una mejora eventual con respecto a las anteriores respuestas está en el uso del `LEFT JOIN` y el `ISNULL` que nos permite "contar" también aquellos artículos que no tienen ubicaciones.